# Python Pandas subsetting based on Dates

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I got a dataframe (using pandas) which contains the following fields:

1. Datesf-----------Price
2. 02/08/16 17:28--10
3. 02/08/16 17:29--20
4. 02/08/16 17:30--30
5. 03/08/16 09:00--40
6. 04/08/16 09:00--50

I am trying to subset the data frame into new dataframes using "Datesf" as a filter. The subsetting should only use the Datesf.Date() part of variable "Datesf" and name the new dataframe "df" as df_date.
for example> new subsetted Dataframe name> df_02_08_16
 1. Datesf------------Price
 2. 02/08/16 17:28--10
 3. 02/08/16 17:29--20
 4. 02/08/16 17:30--30

I tried using the following code but obviously, I am missing out quite a few bits:

```
datelist= df["Datesf"].map(pd.Timestamp.date).unique()

for d in datelist:
    print d
   df.loc[df['Datesf'] == '%s' % d]
```

My python skills are relatively basic at this stage. so forgive me if my query is not so challenging.
Many thanks.
regards,
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['02/08/16 17:28',1], ['02/08/16 17:28',10],['02/08/16 17:28',100],['03/08/16 17:28',101],['04/08/16 17:28',103]], columns=['Datesf', 'Price'])
df.Datesf = pd.to_datetime(df.Datesf)

unique_dates = df.Datesf.unique()
data_frame_dict = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in unique_dates}

for n, key in enumerate(data_frame_dict.keys()):
    print ' ==== dataframe %d ======' % n
    data_frame_dict[key] = df[:][df.Datesf == key]
    print data_frame_dict[key]
    data_frame_dict[key].to_csv('%s.csv'%str(key))
```

Comment: Hello Qmaruf, Your code works perfectly. The only exception being that the code subsets the datasets on the minutes. I wanted to have the data subset done according to the dates, not time. This means that there should be only 3 data frames created : dataframe1 should have date 02/08/16 with 3 observations. Dataframe2 should have date 03/08/16 with one observations and dataframe3 should have date 04/08/16 with one observations

Comment: Did you check the edited code? It creates three different csv file according to your need.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't know why it does not work for my dataframe, but since it works with your dataframe, i am sure i am making a slight mistake